# Google Earth: ERR_CREATE_PLUGIN

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I am getting an error when I use the Google Earth API. The error message is: ERR_CREATE_PLUGIN or in the browser google earth displays a message saying there has been an error with the plugin. I tried it in Chrome/Firefox/IE and have the same issue or complete whitespace where the google earth interface should be.

Now for my code, I would think my code is typical as per the tutorial on google's website. The primary difference is that I do not call it on page load. I have a bootstrap tab divdier that is loaded as a callback to another action. The map is loaded then. Through debugging the following code, I know that calling google.earth.createInstance results in a call to failureCB, but the error message is not very useful at all

```
function initCB(instance) {
        var ge = instance;
        var lookAt = ge.createLookAt('');
        lookAt.setLatitude(lat);
        lookAt.setLongitude(lng);
}
function failureCB(e, m) {
    alert(e);
}
google.earth.createInstance('googleEarthTool', initCB, failureCB);
```

Any ideas on where I should go? Website at: http://beta.snowgeek.org/tools/trip-planning

Answer (score 1):

The `ERR_CREATE_PLUGIN` issue is almost certainly to do with how you are loading the plug-in. You say...

> "The primary difference is that I do not call it on page load."

...but you need to wait until the Google Earth Api has finished loading before you call

`google.earth.createInstance`

Typically this would be done via either `setOnLoadCallback` or else via the `onLoad` handler for the document body, e.g.

```
function init() {
  google.earth.createInstance('googleEarthTool', initCB, failureCB);
}
```

then...

`google.setOnLoadCallback(init);`

or

`<body onload="init()">`

**EDIT**

From looking at your code I can't see that you ever call

`ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);`

To actually display the plugin - surly you would need to do something like

```
this.displayGoogleEarth = function(lat, lng) {
        function initCB(instance) {
           var ge = instance;
           ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true); //actually display the plugin
```

Also, there is an error in how you are loading the api.

`google.load("earth", "1", { "other_params" : "sensor={true_or_false}" });`

Should be

`google.load("earth", "1", { "other_params" : "sensor=true" });`

or

`google.load("earth", "1", { "other_params" : "sensor=false" });`

Comment: That doesn't really address the problem I have. My application allows the page to load, waits for the user to enter some text. Then upon clicking a button which fires an ajax call. As a callback to that ajax call, I call a method similar to the initCB I defined in my question. Google earth should have had more than enough time to load itself by then. The website is launched at present, a sample of the currently not functioning plugin is here under the Maps -> Google Earth tab. http://snowgeek.org/tools/trip-planning#search/Pilot%20Peak%2C%20Boise%20National%20Forest%2C%20Idaho%2083622%2C%20USA

Comment: @Fraser I have the same error only if I hide the container div (using display:none). I looked at some error.js served by google and the error code is an alias for INVALID DIV or ID_NOT_FOUND.
I've solved this by hiding the element just after createInstance. But it looks bad and hackish. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Wissem you should post your own question. That said, rather than hiding the div you can simply set the width/height to 0.